# How to swap array of different types using C++ template?

Tags: c++

Would it be ok to write something like the code below?

```
template<class Temp, class Temp2>
void swaps_arr(Temp* arr, Temp2* arr2, int N){

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      Temp currentArrItem = arr[i];

      arr[i] = (Temp)arr2[i];
      arr2[i] = (Temp2)currentArrItem;
    }
}
```

I wrote a show method.

```
template<class Temp, class Temp2>
void show(Temp* arr, Temp2* arr2, int N){
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) cout << arr[i] << " "; cout << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) cout << arr2[i] << " "; cout << endl;
}
```

Then I called these function as below;

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   int N = 8;

   int* arr = new int[N];
   char * arr2 = new char[N];

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) arr[i] = i + 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) arr2[i] = 'A';

   show(arr, arr2, N);
   swaps_arr(arr, arr2, N);
   cout << "After swapping" << endl;
   show(arr, arr2, N);
}
```

It works for double and int. But for char it doesn't.

Comment: I test it but didn't work for char vs int.

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? Please edit your question to include the current and expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> It works for double and int. But for char it doesn't.

It works, but you may not be getting the output you expect.

First, you are filling your array of ints with the numbers 1 to 8:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) arr[i] = i + 1;
```

Then you are swapping both arrays, so now you have an array of chars with the values 1 to 8.

Finally, you print that array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) cout << arr2[i] << " "; cout << endl;
```

Every `arr2[i]` is printed as a char of value 1 to 8. Those are "control characters" (delete, escape, end of line...). You would see ["printable characters"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) if the values of those characters were between 32 and 126.

Just change your example filling the array of ints with values that correspond to "printable characters":

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) arr[i] = i + 'A';
```

And you will get this output:

```
65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 
A A A A A A A A 
After swapping
65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 
A B C D E F G H
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/zjoq3rn8P)

---

Another way of implementing the swapping function would be:

- Using the `transform` algorithm to loop through `arr` and `arr2`.
- Using `exchange` to copy the contents of each element `x` in `arr` to an `x2` in `arr2`, and return the old value of `x2`.
- Assigning that old value of `x2` to `x`. This is done by `transform` getting the lambda's return value and writing it to `arr` (4th argument).

```cpp
template<class Temp, class Temp2>
void swaps_arr(Temp* arr, Temp2* arr2, int N)
{
    std::transform(arr, arr + N, arr2, arr,
        [](Temp& x, Temp2& x2){ return std::exchange(x2, x); });
}
```

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/vbEEe741q)

Answer (score -1):

It will only work, if Temp and Temp2 are from the same class. If not, there will be some behaviour I imagine you do not want, like implicit casting.

```
template<class Temp>
void swaps_arr(Temp* arr, Temp* arr2, int N){

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  Temp currentArrItem = arr[i];

  arr[i] = (Temp)arr2[i];
  arr2[i] = (Temp2)currentArrItem;
}
}
```

Comment: So I can only make this swapping for types that can change?

Comment: There is no such thing as implicit casting. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The term you're looking for is "implicit conversion".

Comment: Re: "Temp and Temp2 are from the same class" -- no, that's not the case. Being able to exchange objects of two different types requires that the types be convertible. It's certainly possible to write a class `Temp` that can be converted to `Temp2` and a class `Temp2` that can be converted to `Temp`. That's similar to the inter-conversions between`int` and `double` that the question says work.